# Express does not return all query string parameters

Tags: node.js, express

Route

```
app.get('/pdf/:id', function(req, res) {
```

Request

```
GET http://localhost/pdf/123?option=456&clientId=789
```

I only get

```
req.query == { option: '456' }
req.params == { id: '123' }
```

How comes the second query parameter is cut off? My delimiter is a standard '&'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are using curl or some terminal command, & has a special meaning there. Try gettig it inside quotes as

```
curl 'http://localhost/pdf/123?option=456&clientId=789'
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that earlier

Comment: Yep... I was having the same problem and stumbled upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working:

```
app.get('/pdf/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(req.query);

    res.end();
});
```

Output:

```
[ id: '123' ]
{ option: '456', clientId: '789' }
GET /pdf/123?option=456&clientId=789 200 1ms
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I'm doing, no? Same thing on Express v3 and v4. The only difference I see is that v4 uses an object for req.params, not an array. When I flip the query params, again only the first one is available.